# Error with Jersey REST API on tomcat startup

Tags: rest, tomcat, jersey

I have a REST webservice project using the below dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hdrhistogram</groupId>
            <artifactId>HdrHistogram</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

But when i start my tomcat server it gives me error as :-

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/client/RxInvokerProvider
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getJaxRsProviderInterfaces(Providers.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.<clinit>(Providers.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.ComponentBag.modelFor(ComponentBag.java:518)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.ComponentBag.lambda$registerModel$10(ComponentBag.java:477)
```

I tried with different versions of javax.ws.rs including 2.0.1 , 2.1 and even the milestone version m01.

What is the dependency i am missing ?

Comment: What repositories are you using? Could you add what's in your `<repositories>`, please? BTW `RxInvokerProvider` was added in version 2.1, so 2.0.1 wouldn't work.

Comment: There is nothing in <repositories> tag. I have some additional jersey dependencies :- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: Try removing the `javax.ws.rs-api` dependency as `jersey-client` propagates this dependency to your project already.

Comment: I tried the same. Actually, i added the javax.ws.rs-api after having the above error in tomcat startup.org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [Welcome] in web application [/adh-rest-ccr] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.client.RxInvokerProvider

Comment: Additional info : When i hit the service , i receive below exception :-   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet Welcome
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers
 at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.ComponentBag.modelFor(ComponentBag.java:518)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.ComponentBag.lambda$registerModel$10(ComponentBag.java:477)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)